# How to fetch a random word of a specific category in Python using the requests module?

Tags: python, python-3.x, heroku, python-requests

I am working on a Python project in which I need to fetch a random word from an API such as Heroku, but only of a specific category, for example "Fruits", or "Colors". I was able to fetch random words using this code:

```py
import requests
import random

try:
    url = "https://random-word-api.herokuapp.com/word?number=1"
    response = requests.get(url)
    words = response.json()
    random_word = random.choice(words)
    print(random_word)
except:
    print("Error fetching data from API")
```

I just need help implementing the "categories" feature now. Can someone please help?

I tried to fetch a random word of a specific category using this block of code:

```
import requests
import random

try:
    url = "https://random-word-api.herokuapp.com/word?number=1&category=fruits"
    response = requests.get(url)
    words = response.json()
    random_word = random.choice(words)
    print(random_word)
except:
    print("Error fetching data from API")
```

I expected to get a random fruit name, such as "Apple" or "Orange", but I got the message:

> "Error fetching data from API"

(specified in the except block), which means an exception occurred.

Comment: Please remove the try/except, run your code again, and then [edit] the question to include the _complete_ error traceback. We aren't able to guess what the error might be.

Answer (score -2):

```
import requests

def fetch_random_word(category):
    base_url = 'https://wordsapiv1.p.rapidapi.com/words/'
    headers = {
        'X-RapidAPI-Host': 'wordsapiv1.p.rapidapi.com',
        'X-RapidAPI-Key': 'YOUR_RAPIDAPI_KEY',  # Replace with your actual RapidAPI key
    }

    # Make a request to the Words API
    response = requests.get(base_url, headers=headers, params={'random': 'true', 'category': category})

    # Check if the request was successful (status code 200)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        data = response.json()
        random_word = data['word']
        return random_word
    else:
        # If the request was not successful, print an error message
        print(f"Error: {response.status_code}")
        return None

# Example: Fetch a random word from the category 'food'
random_food_word = fetch_random_word('food')

if random_food_word:
    print(f"Random word in the 'food' category: {random_food_word}")
else:
    print("Failed to fetch a random word.")
```

Comment: Can you please clarify why there is a need to make the code so lengthy as compared to my original code, just for choosing a category of the word? I think there is some issue with the URL I used in my code. Please look for any problems in that if possible.

Comment: Are you aware of our [policy forbidding AI-generated answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831/354577)?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).